# Why BlueGriffon is not in the repo?

Tags: html, web-development, css

BlueGriffon is not in repositories. Is it dead ? If so can you tell me about any alternative ?

Comment: Last release was in 2013. Probably the project is dead, the software may work.

Comment: I am actually using it (1.7.2 on 14.04). Looking at this: http://bluegriffon.org/post/2015/04/20/BlueGriffon-progress-20150420 it is still maintained, although the Linux version is a bit behind at the moment. Why not contact them: http://bluegriffon.org/pages/Contacts

Comment: @JacobVlijm - thats probably a worthwhile answer :). I'm going to try and [compile a new version](http://bluegriffon.org/pages/Build-BlueGriffon) and if that results in 1.7~ contact them and ask whether code is available for the [1.8](http://bluegriffon.org/freshmeat/1.8.0pre/), because i must of been using 1.7.2 for AGES....

Comment: Through the [twitter feed](https://twitter.com/BlueGriffonApp) found a *slightly* newer version is available for Ubuntu 14.04 from [here](http://bluegriffon.org/freshmeat/nightlies/20141127/). I am also guessing the available source code is for 1.7.3 so I think I may ask if the source for 1.8 is available...

Comment: BlueGriffon is not dead: http://bluegriffon.org/post/2015/10/14/BlueGriffon-1.8-released

Answer (score 2):

Install the GetDeb repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc)-getdeb apps"
wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

and BlueGriffon

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bluegriffon
```

[image]

<sub>BlueGriffon (Vivid)</sub>